# Extracting strings with labels in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract strings with labels from text data in python.I have written following code written , but this replaces the actual data with the string , i want to extract that

```
    import re
def replace_entities(example):

# dd mm yyyy
example = re.sub("(\d{1,31}(:? |\-|\/)\d{1,12}(:? |\-|\/)\d{4})", "DATESTR", example)  # dd/mm/yyyy
example = re.sub("(\d{4}(:? |\-|\/)\d{1,31}(:? |\-|\/)\d{1,12})", "DATESTR", example)  # yyyy/dd/mm

# email id
example = re.sub("[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+", "EMAILIDSTR", example)

# URL
example = re.sub('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', "URLSTR",
                    example)
example = re.sub('www.(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', "URLSTR", example)

# TIME
example = re.sub("\d{2}:\d{2} (:?AM|PM|am|pm)", "TIMESTR", example)
example = re.sub("\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3} (:?AM|PM|am|pm)", "TIMESTR", example)

# MONEY
example = re.sub(r'\£ \d+', "MONEYSTR", example, 0)
example = re.sub(r'\£\d+', "MONEYSTR", example, 0)
example = re.sub(r'\d+(:?\£|pound|pounds|euros|euro)', "MONEYSTR", example, 0)
example = re.sub(r'\d+ (:?\£|pound|pounds|euros|euro)', "MONEYSTR", example, 0)
example = re.sub(r'\d.\d+(:?\£|pound|pounds|euros|euro)', "MONEYSTR", example, 0)
example = re.sub(r'\d.\d+ (:?\£|pound|pounds|euros|euro)', "MONEYSTR", example, 0)
example = re.sub(r'\\xc2\\xa\d+', "MONEYSTR", example, 0)
example = re.sub(r'\\xc2\\xa\d+.\d+', "MONEYSTR", example, 0)

# Split alpha numeric and sp. symbol
example = " ".join(re.findall(r"[^,.:;\(\)\/\\_]+|[,.:;\(\)\/\\_]", example))
example = " ".join(re.findall(r"[^\d_]+|\d+", example))
example = re.sub('(?!^)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r' \1', example)

# NUMBERS
example = re.sub(r'\d+', 'NUMSTR', example)

return example
```

I have following text as input :

```
 My name is ali, Date is 21/08/2018 Total amount is euros 10 . Account number is 123456
```

Expected_output is:

```
> 21/08/2018: DATESTR
  euros 10 : MONEYSTR
  123456  :  NUMSTR
```

How can i get above output

Any ideas?

Comment: Unclear: should "My name is ALi Date is " be removed, as per your 'expected_output'?

Answer (score 2):

You may fix it by adding `.*?` before and `.*` after the pattern you have and replace with `r'\1 : DATESTR'`

```
 res = re.sub(r'.*?(\d{1,31}(?::? |[-/])\d{1,12}(?::? |[-/])\d{4}).*', r'\1 : DATESTR', s)
```

See the  [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VRdY41/1/). With `.*?` you match any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, and with `.*` you match any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and that way you remove what you do not need by just matching and you keep what you capture.

You may also use your regex to *extract* the date and then append `: DATESTR` to it:

```
import re
rx = r"\d{1,31}(?::? |[-/])\d{1,12}(?::? |[-/])\d{4}"
s = "My name is ALi Date is 09/03/2018"
m = re.search(rx, s)
if m:
    print("{} : DATESTR".format(m.group())) # => 09/03/2018 : DATESTR
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/3lqBfl).

Comment: What does 's' represents here?

Comment: @CyleySimon See the snippet, `s` is the input string.

Comment: Stribizew  What if these is for multiple regex ? How should i Apply for Multiple Regex

Comment: Please precise the question, I do not have a clue.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew hi I have updated the above question . can you please check and suggest some thing. Thank you

Comment: @CyleySimon From what you have, it seems you may just go on using your patterns, but apply the logic in the second part of my answer. Run each regex and append the line to the result if a match was found.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/S2cejj, this is what I suggest (you can finish converting the code yourself following the same logic).

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [datefinder](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder)
Here I have tried to get your example done with it:

```
>>> import datefinder
>>> str = 'My name is ALi Date is 09/03/2018'
>>> matches = datefinder.find_dates(str)
>>> for i in matches:
...     print(i.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") + ':DATESTR')
...
09/03/2018:DATESTR
```

I guess this will help you. It can get any date string out of your string.

Answer (score 0):

from your example you want to do 2 things:

1. Find a date-like string
2. Add another string at the end of your match

The solution I propose here might not be the best but it does the thing. I propose you get the match that your regex can find, and then use that match to format whatever you want to print.

```
import re

string1 = "My name is ALi Date is 09/03/2018"
string2 = "DATESTR"
m = re.search("(\d{1,31}(:? |\-|\/)\d{1,12}(:? |\-|\/)\d{4})", string1 ) # match the date : dd/mm/yyyy
print( m.group(0) + ' : ' + string2 )
```

The output is:

```
>>> 09/03/2018 : DATESTR
```

There might be some other functions that fit your needs in the documentation. That's what I just used.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html